# include or require are not working in Lamp

Tags: php, apache, lampp

i have tried both require and include functions to load file named as 'Base.php'. but could not worked . my directory path is following.

```
/var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.co/code/AALM/Config/Base.php
```

i am sure file is clearly exists in directory. i have checked via file_exists() function too.

1)why my file is not loaded through include or require;
2)no error is displaying , even i have changed `display error =on` in php.ini file .

suggest me to solve this issue or to get an exactly error
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see some code? There could be many reasons why it's not working.

Comment: If your test with `file_exists()` really succeeded with really the same path, then the only option left is that some component prevents access. in that case however you would have gotten an entry in your http servers error log file. There is something fishy here. Please show the exact code you tried with the exact path. And the exact content of the relevant time in your http servers error log file.

Comment: Also note that `display error` and `display_error` are two different things.

Comment: i have tried this code . require_once('/var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.com/code/AALM/Config/Base.php');

Answer (score 0):

The file that loads base.php - which folder is it in? If it is in the ecash-staging.co folder then your require function should look like this:

```
require('code/AALM/Config/Base.php');
```

If it is in a sub-folder that needs to go back one folder and then down it should be preceeded by .. like this:

```
require('../AALM/Config/Base.php');
```

Otherwise you could try (for testing only) the long way and that is to put the full URL like this:

```
require('http://ecash-staging.co/code/AALM/Config/Base.php');
```

Comment: why does not my php showing error . i am using lamp

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);     by adding this , top of the script , worked for me to display an error .

Answer (score 0):

i have added these lines in top of php script file for error rendering .

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);
```

and used require_once like this.

`require_once(/var/www/vhosts/ecash-staging.com/code/AALM/Config/Base.php)`;

it worked for me properly .